# In Outlook Web App 2010, Create Repeating Meeting, and Decline Single Appointments of It

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, exchange-2010

I am the organizer for a repeating meeting. I am also part of this meeting. For specific dates, I cannot attend, but *the meeting is still held* with the other participants. I want to decline these single dates, so the others see I will not attend.

Problem: If I edit the meeting occurrence, there are no buttons to accept/decline this single appointment, as I am the organizer.

Comment: Since you are the Organizer you were never invited, so there nothing to "decline".

Comment: I'd like others to know for which of the meetings I created I will be attending.

Answer (score 0):

Create and use a dummy account as the 'organizer' and invite yourself along with the others. That way you can decline the invite as needed.